# Cannot read property from JS "object"

Tags: javascript

I want to read the property (username) of a JS object, but it seems that the property does not exist, although I can print the entire object (also the username) in my browser's console.

```
console.log(usersInMember[0].username); // undefined
console.log(typeof usersInMember[0]); // object
console.log(typeof usersInMember[0].username); // undefined
console.log(usersInMember[0]); // prints complete object -> [Object { _id="amydYGA4uCLuKLY84", createdAt=Date, roles=[3], more...}]
console.log(usersInMember[0].hasOwnProperty("username")); // false
```

Object (Screenshot 1):
[image: Screenshot]

Screenshot 2:

[image: Screenshot]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the property `username` exists in `usersInMember[0]` object? Also post your full `usersInMember[0]` object log.

Comment: Printing the `usersInMember` object will show you whether or not that object has the `username` member. Obviously, we know it doesn’t since `hasOwnProperty` came back false. Where are you setting this member? Why do you believe the object ought to contain the member?

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses! I edited my post and added a screenshot. As you can see the property "username" exists.

Comment: Are you sure the `usersInMember` have array of objects?

Comment: The property certainly seems to exist in the screenshot, assuming that's the log of `usersInMember[0]`. Are you sure the `username` property name doesn't have an accidental space at the end or something like that?

Comment: Yes I am sure that the `usersInMember` is an array of objects, because I can add more users and view the objects in the array from the browser's console: [Screenshot2](http://abload.de/img/screenshot2014-03-08awvkk4.png). And the property does not have any accidental space at the end.

Comment: Could be a race condition. The console object is live. Are you fetching the object asynchronously?

Comment: Yes, I am using the Meteor framework.

Comment: Are you sure you access the object **after** the server replied?